# Sitecore Commerce Server was unable to log an event

Tags: com, sitecore, dcom, commerce, sitecore-commerce-server

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce Server 11.3 + Sitecore 8.1. I am following all steps from dev.sitecore.net. When I install it on Windows 10, everything is ok, I am able to connect Sitecore with Commerce server. But when I do same steps on Windows 2008 R2

*Commerce Server was unable to log an event.  Please make sure that the identity of the Commerce Server Event Logging COM+ application is an account that has permissions to log events (the Component Services MMC can be used to configure this).*

Stack Trace:
*[COMException (0x80070006): Commerce Server was unable to log an event.  Please make sure that the identity of the Commerce Server Event Logging COM+ application is an account that has permissions to log events (the Component Services MMC can be used to configure this).]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14579646
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   CommerceServer.Core.Configuration.ISiteConfigReadOnly.Initialize(String bstrSiteName) +0
   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Configuration.CommerceResourceCollection..ctor(String siteName) +227
   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.CommerceApplicationModule.InitializeApplication() +587
   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.CommerceApplicationModule.Init(HttpApplication appInstance) +160
   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Pipelines.CommerceBaseModuleProcessor`1.Init(PipelineArgs args) +143
   (Object , Object[] ) +83
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +445
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +188
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +516
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +571
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +452
[HttpException (0x80004005): Commerce Server was unable to log an event.  Please make sure that the identity of the Commerce Server Event Logging COM+ application is an account that has permissions to log events (the Component Services MMC can be used to configure this).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +778*

I compared COM configurations of Commerce server on Windows 10 and Windows 2008 R2, but have not found any changes.
How to give Commerce Server Event Logging COM+ enough permissions to access log?
Or how this issue could be resolved in other way?
Any suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: Not much idea regarding Sitecore Commerce Server, but could you please check impersonate settings in web.config, if true then try setting it false and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Windows 2008 R2 I used domain credentials while installation. When I created local user and used his credentials, everything start work fine.